# Trying to get IMCE with Filefield Sources working (no Upload button in popup)

Tags: 6, media, files

I've got a clean install of D6.22, CCK, Filefield, ImageField, Filefield Sources and IMCE. No other modules.

When i go to http://mysite.com/imce it all works perfectly [(see screenshot)](http://coob.co.uk/binhole/misc/IMCE%20win.png).

But when i try to implement an image field with IMCE as a filefield source, i can click the "browse" link and the IMCE popup comes up, but the only button i get at the top of the popup is "Insert file". No upload, no delete, no resize etc. [Here's the screenshot](http://coob.co.uk/binhole/misc/IMCE%20fail.png).

I see from the popup's page info that its URL is...
http://mysite.com/filefield/imce/page/field_pics?app=pics|url@edit-field-pics-0-imce-path
(the image field's human name and machine_name are both "pics").
I'm logged in as user-1, and the IMCE user-1 profile is looking good.

Also, there are no javascript errors, and if inspect the popup with Firebug, the upload button is there, but hidden. If I unhide it and click the button, I get the alert "You can not perform this operation". So it seems to be a permissions problem rather than a javascript problem.

I'm sure i've missed something so simple nobody's bothered to mention it in any of the docs. Can someone enlighten me?!

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Like, Filefield Sources no longer lets IMCE do anything except browse your files and select one of them (for security reasons i think). That's what the situation *seems* to be, though i can't find anywhere that says that explicitly.

Luckily there's a patch which reinstates the missing functionality...

http://drupal.org/node/877452#comment-4499144

The maintainer of Filefield Sources links to that patch from the module's project page, so it's a recommended patch.

All functioning now :) Can i have my Sunday back now please?

++Thanks to ufku for providing the patch.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the patch (thank's to chichilatte) you have to check the file browser mode "Full" under field settings -> file sources -> imce file browser settings. Otherwise you can not rename, delete or upload a file.